# How to use Sequel with PostGIS

Tags: ruby, postgis, sequel

I am using the [Sequel gem](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/index.html) to access multiple postgres databases.
The databases partially use the [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) extension. There is a postgis adapter for ActiveRecord, but I haven't found one for Sequel.

So my current solution is to use raw SQL to query postgis based data.
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Currently using raw sql in AR as well, so no, I think raw sql may be the most plain solution for this.